# WordPress - 404 Not Found nginx /only few users/

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404

I‘ve got a 404 problem on my blog. Lot‘s of people was reporting **"404 Not Found nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)" on Page 2, 3, someone on posts..** I eliminated problem on smaller group of people when changed **Permalinks from Post name to Plain, and changed from 15 to 9 posts on homepage** /thats not good/, but It did *not solve the problem completely*.

STILL some of users reporting 404 nginx, some people solved the problem with **crearing cache** and some users recommended **New private tab** to work properly.

For me its working all fine, so, Its hard to test it.

***I tried*** :

- reinstall WP core files
- disabling all plugins for few minutes
- change theme for few minutes
- there is no .htacces on nginx
- nginx config is configured properly, with "try_files" /in the past it worked/

I think, that must be some problem with **permalinks**/pagination ? Maybe. I tried other plugin for pagination, too.

Some tips ? Thank you.

**Audit Log Viewer shows something like:**

```
Request URL example.org/?author=7 Referer ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take hosting support if possible.

Comment: Its hosted on friends server. He is hosting many websites, I think, from this side is everything ok.